# Why the value to explained various ratio is too low in binary classification problem?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, pca

My input data  $X$ has 100 samples and 1724 features. I want to classify my data into two classes. But explained various ratio value is too low like 0.05,0.04, No matter how many principal components I fix while performing PCA. I have seen in the literature that usually explained variance ratio is close to 1. I'm unable to understand my mistake. I tried to perform PCA by reducing number of features and increasing number of samples. But it doesn't make any significant effect on my result.

```
`pca = PCA(n_components=10).fit(X)
Xtrain = pca.transform(X)
explained_ratio=pca.explained_variance_ratio_
EX=explained_ratio
fig,ax1=plt.subplots(ncols=1,nrows=1)

ax1.plot(np.arange(len(EX)),EX,marker='o',color='blue')
ax1.set_ylabel(r"$\lambda$")
ax1.set_xlabel("l")
```

Comment: With so few samples and so many features you probably won't get much out of anything unless you apply domain knowledge to pick the proper variables

Comment: But even if I use  feature numbers 20 or 30 using 100 samples and I set n_components=10 I still get small values of explained variance ration. Can you please specify what kind of changes can improve my result?